# How do you get textareas working in a custom component?

Tags: javascript, web-component

I've been cleaning up some plain javascript code I have and I thought it would be a good opportunity to learn how to do web components. I have the buttons working but the inputs/textareas are being a pain. Currently, they are completely unclickable and uneditable.

I've tried a few different things the internet has suggested but I'm just getting errors. I imagine I have to initialise them or something first but I can't really find any resources on that.

Here's the template:

```
const template = document.createElement('template');
template.innerHTML = `

<div class="draggable-element">
    <div class="title">
        <input type="text" class="name" placeholder = "Sound Change Title...">
        <button class="delete">&#x2715;</button>
        <button class="maxmin">–</button>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        <textarea class="rule" spellcheck="false" rows=3 placeholder="Enter rules here..." ></textarea>
        <textarea class="description" rows=5 placeholder="Rule description..."></textarea>
    </div>
</div>
`;
```

And here's the relevant code I have so far:

```
class SoundRule extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
        super();

        this.attachShadow({mode:'open'});
        
        this.name = this.shadowRoot.querySelector('.name');
        this.rule = this.shadowRoot.querySelector('.rule');
        this.desc = this.shadowRoot.querySelector('.description');

        this.shadowRoot.appendChild(template.content.cloneNode(true));
    }
}

window.customElements.define('sound-rule', SoundRule);
```

Comment: It actually works for me.

Comment: @ChristianFritz  oh, really? That's definitely not the case on my end. [This is what I've got.](https://imgur.com/a/eQd59y6) Top is the component-based implementation and the bottom is the basic javascript.

Comment: @ChristianFritz ah, I've found the culprit. I'm using JQuery UI to drag and drop sort, it seems to be somehow breaking the component.

Answer (score 0):

That `template` is a very expensive construct for adding HTML.

Only when you use the template **content** multiple times does it have advantage.

```html
<my-text></my-text>
<script>
  customElements.define('my-text', class extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
      super()
        .attachShadow({mode: 'open'})
        .innerHTML = `<textarea class="rule" spellcheck="false" rows=3 placeholder="Enter rules here..." ></textarea>`;

      this.rule = this.shadowRoot.querySelector('.rule');
    }
  });
  </script>
```